# Scrape some text from another website without any url or special charecters

Tags: php, curl, web

I'm trying to learn some using of code, and i'm trying to **scrape** information or some text from another site to my (for personal usage only).

well, for example i want to take information from this site :

```
http://en.sratim.co.il/tt1150273/ROOM-(2015)/
```

i'm tried to **scrape** the year like :

```
$year = explode( '<span class="yearpronobold">' , $content );
$year_end = explode("</span>" , $year[1] );
```

but result was :

```
<a href="browse.php?uy=2015&amp;fy=2015">2015</a>
```

and i want result only the number 2015

also couldn't **scrape** the actors

> Actors:   William H. Macy, Joan Allen (I), Brie Larson, Cas Anvar,
> Randal Edwards, Megan Park, Chantelle Chung

it gives me `ARAY`

can anyone explain me what to do?
i'm tried to search on google bit it didn't gave the right result what i', searching for.
thank you for any help.

Comment: FYI it’s __scrape__ (and __scraper__, __scraping__, __scraped__) not scrap

Answer (score 1):

```
include "simple_html_dom.php";

function doStrips($getString) {
    $getString  = strip_tags($getString);
    return $getString!="" ? $getString : "N/A";
}

$mainUrl= "http://en.sratim.co.il/";
$url    = "http://en.sratim.co.il/tt1150273/ROOM-(2015)/";
$ch     = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$html           = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($server_output);
$releaseYear    = $html->find('.yearpronobold');
$actorDetails   = $html->find('a[itemprop="actors"]');
$directorDetails= $html->find('a[itemprop="director"]');
$getDuration    = $html->find('time[itemprop="duration"]');
$publishedDate  = $html->find('time[itemprop="datePublished"]');
$getGenre       = $html->find('span[itemprop="genre"]');
$getImage       = $html->find('img[itemprop="image"]');

//print_r($getImage);

echo "Release Year - ".doStrips($releaseYear[0]->children(0))."<br />";
echo "Actor(s) - ".doStrips(implode(", ",$actorDetails))."<br />";
echo "Director - ".doStrips(implode(", ",$directorDetails))."<br />";
echo "Duration - ".doStrips(implode(", ",$getDuration))."<br />";
echo "Published Date - ".doStrips(implode(", ",$publishedDate))."<br />";
echo "Genre - ".doStrips(implode(", ",$getGenre))."<br />";
echo "Image - <img src='".$mainUrl.$getImage[0]->attr["src"]."' /><br />";
```

Before all, you need to check whether `php_curl` is enabled on your server.
http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php tutorial on `PHP_CURL`.

here is the output what i received..
[image]

Comment: it give me outpot `Wrong Input`

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/ download the simple_html_dom.php from here..

Comment: i downloaded the file and uploaded it to the same directory if my file. but the result is wrong input http://i.imgur.com/UkOm8ga.png

Comment: Please post your code, what you made changes.. So that I can be clear with your problem.. Thanks..

Comment: i didn't change any code just copy paste...  should i change something in simple_html_dom? here error from new edit **`[31-Jan-2016 13:16:08 America/Chicago] PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function children() on a non-object in /home/otzxuwui/public_html/sratim/index.php on line 30`**

Comment: Did you use the same URL as well!! I have added the screen shot as well.. Which I added to show my output..

Comment: hey, check result please [link](http://imgur.com/cETlavS) and code [link](http://imgur.com/VFoj94E) and i want the result show `http://en.sratim.co.il/contents/Actors/Images/Thumbnails/7/thumb_167.jpg` `Ryan Gosling` i'm tried to learn some from this site [link](http://rcodex.com/code/develop-a-scrapper-get-content-from-other-website-using-php/) but there is no option like i need .. or i did something wrong. Thanks for help!